# i am using http2 with express , getting error "Cannot set deprecated header: connection"

Tags: express, http-proxy, http2

I am using http2 and express in my application. and using http-proxy to proxy requests to other APIs. when i hit an proxy API in express, i am getting "Cannot set deprecated header: connection". It seems http-proxy adds connection header automatically which is deprecated. I tried with "request" instead of http-proxy, still the same error.

Comment: Isn't it the remote side that you're proxying to that it setting that header?

Comment: let's say from browser m hitting /getdata, it goes to express , there i am using http-proxy which will translate /getdata in to let's say http://www.example.com/getdata and will hit this. Here http-proxy is setting the header.

Comment: If you're using `request` instead of `http-proxy` and the problem persists, it's not `http-proxy` that sets the header. If you pass the remote response data as-is, including headers, it may be that it's being caused by that. Try removing any `connection` headers from the remote response before passing it back to the HTTP/2 client.

Comment: i want to serve files over http2 but data APIs should be on http1 as they may not support http2 yet. maybe this is the problem. i am trying to access http1 supported APIs over http2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was http-proxy's issue. http-proxy tries to write connection header which is not allowed in http2 causing error.